# Imputation using related data (R)

Tags: r, missing-data, panel-data

I have a panel dataset with population data. I am working mostly with two vectors - population and households. The household vector(there are 3 countries) has a substantial amount of missing values, the population vector is full. I use a model with population as the independent variable to get the missing values of households. What function should I use to extract these values? I do not need to make any forecasts, just to imput the missing data.
Thank you.

EDIT:
This is a printscreen of my dataset:
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1366x440q90/661/RAH3uh.jpg
As you can see, many values of datatype = "original" data are missing and I need to input it somehow. I have created several panel data models (Pooled, within, between) and without further considerations tried to extract the missing data with each of them; however I do not know how to do this.

EDIT 2: What I need is not how to determine which model to use but how to get the missing values(so making the dataset more balanced) of the model.

Comment: Could you provide a small example dataset so we can better understand what we are dealing with? What function is appropriate also depends (in part) on what question you are trying to answer. What does your analysis look like?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question; hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Without knowing what analysis you want to do, there is no way of suggesting an appropriate method. You should think about that before choosing an imputation method. For starters you could have a look at the `mice` package, and use the first few columns and the available data per year to impute the missing values on the "missing" years. This method, however, will ignore the panel structure and might be erronous to some degree. But that depends on what analysis you're trying to do.

Comment: All of my analysis is predicting the missing data. I do not need to make any forecasts for the future, only to make my panel dataset balanced.

Comment: I was saying you probably want to establish a balanced dataset for a reason, e.g. estimating the trend over time within each country/population; or the variance of the trend across countries/populations; or whether trend-differences between populations vary across countries... What I am saying is that your analysis might have the clustered variance structure of panel data in mind. Not all imputation models support such variance structures. You can try with `mice` using the cluster indicators as predictors. Without details from your side regarding your analyses, I'm afraid I can't help further.

Comment: Another option that is able to preserve clustered variance structures on two levels is the `pan` package that is designed to impute panel data. However, `mice` is easier to use and more flexible with different types of variables (`pan` assumes a joint normal distribution for target variables, which might still be okay in your case). `pan` can be a very plausible method for normal panel data if used properly.